# C variable undeclared

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program in C were you have to guess a random number. I made an `if` statement that checks if the input matches the answer but the `int` I made the answer says it's undeclared.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int myNum;

void An() {
    if (myNum == anNum) {
        printf("Correct! \n\n");
    } else {
        printf ("Wrong guess again \n");
        guess();
    }     
}

void guess () {
    scanf("%d", &myNum);
    An(); 
}

int main () {

    int anNum = (rand() % 10) + 1;

    printf("%d", anNum);
    srand(time(0));
    printf("Guess the number from 1-10! \n");
    guess();
     
    return 0;
}
```

I tried declaring the variable in the header but that didn't work and I tried making a separate function but that also didn't work

Comment: `anNum` is local to the `main()` function, it's not visible in `an()`. You should pass it as an argument to `guess()`, which should then pass it to `An()`.

Comment: it's best to show some error output if you can

Comment: Or you could use a global variable like you do with `myNum`.

Comment: read up on variable scoping. Essentially anything declared inside `{ ... }` isn't visible outside of that.

Comment: Be careful with the circular calls .. `guess` calls `An` which can call `guess` which calls `An` .. etc. It would take a while, but enough of that would eventually blow up your stack. Instead you should set up a loop that calls these functions until the user has guessed correctly.

Comment: You should also move your seeding `srand` call to _before_ your call to `rand()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable anNum should be declared either globally or in the function where it has been used. So, in order to rectify your error you need to pass anNum to guess() function then again you have to pass anNum from guess() to An() function by using arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int myNum;

//For the below function You have to declare the function with the respective data type here in this case is 'int' because of the arguments we have used.//

int An(a,b) 
{
    if(a==b)
    {
        printf("Correct! \n\n");
    } 
    else {
        printf ("Wrong guess again \n");
        guess(b);
    }     
}

    int guess (x) {
    int anNum=x;
    int myNum;
    scanf("%d", &myNum);
    An(myNum,anNum); 
}

int main () {
    srand(time(0));

//Here srand(time(0)) should be used before random number generation

    int anNum = rand() % 10 + 1;    
    printf("%d\n", anNum);
    printf("Guess the number from 1-10! \n");
    guess(anNum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Defining `myNum` both as a global variable and a local one is utmostly confusing.

Comment: You have an indirect recursion: `guess()` -> `An()` -> `guess()`... invalid input for `scanf("%d", &myNum)` such as `Q` will cause an infinite recursion resulting in a **stack overflow** :)

Answer (score 0):

`anNum` is a local variable inside your `main()` function, and it is not visible to `An()`. You should pass this variable from `main()` to `guess()` first, and then pass it to `An()`, like so:

```c
void An(int anNum) {
    if (myNum == anNum)
    {
        printf("Correct! \n\n");
    } else {
        printf ("Wrong guess again \n");
        guess(anNum);
    }     
}

void guess (int number) {
    scanf("%d", &myNum);
    An(number); 
}

int main () {

    int anNum = (rand() % 10) +1;

    printf("%d", anNum);
    srand(time(0));
    printf("Guess the number from 1-10! \n");
    guess(anNum);
     
    return 0;
}
```

In C, everything that is declared inside curly brackets `{ }` is local to that [scope](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm), so you can only use local variables in other functions by [passing it](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm) to them.

Comment: Why not pass both numbers instead of keeping a global variable, which seems especially inappropriate for the `myNum` variable?